# Set Artifactory to only have cache filesystem

Tags: java, nexus, artifactory

**Goal:** My goal is to have Artifactory as a cache mirror of another Java Artifact repository with a maximum cache size (e.g. 10Gb)

**What is implemented:** Artifactory has an option to enable `cache-fs` as a [filestore option](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Filestore#ConfiguringtheFilestore-CachedFilesystemBinaryProvider). I've enabled it through the `binarystore.xml` configuration with the cache size of 10Gb.

**Expectation:** I expected that there's only one filesystem that is cache based. Once the amount of artifacts hit 10Gb, it will start removing the least recently used artifacts.

**Actual Behaviour:** The cache filesystem (`$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/cache`) is created side by side with the default filesystem (`$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore`). The default system will store all the artifacts where the cache is used for quick lookup.

**Question**

Is it possible to only set Artifactory to only have the cache filesystem without the default filesystem?

Comment: Can you please share the logic? If you want only one location just change the location of the $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/filestore to the location that you wish to save the binaries...

Comment: @Ariel, The motivation is wanting a read cache server to offload the requests from the main artifact server. The limitation is however storage,  so the questions is whether there's a LRU based storage layer or are there other ways to tackle this problem like what Dror suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [cache-fs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Filestore#ConfiguringtheFilestore-CachedFilesystemBinaryProvider) is meant to be used as a caching layer on top of other storage layers. The main motivation is improving performance when working with a slow NFS or a remote object storage.
cache-fs cannot be used on its own and requires a [file-system](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Filestore#ConfiguringtheFilestore-FilesystemBinaryProvider), [S3](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Filestore#ConfiguringtheFilestore-S3BinaryProvider) or similar binary provider.
If you would like to limit the storage being used by the Artifactory file system you can set a [storage quota](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage#ManagingDiskSpaceUsage-StorageQuota). Once Artifactory will reach the quota you will not be able to deploy any new artifacts.
If you plan to use Artifactory only for mirroring another repository, you can configure Artifactory to [cleanup unused cached artifacts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage#ManagingDiskSpaceUsage-DeletingUnusedCachedArtifacts) in order to limit storage usage.